# can anyone show me how can i fix error with my NAT config

Tags: networking, cisco, nat

Can anyone help me with my packet tracer problem? My network 2 buildings (each building has 3 vlans) on the same side and it has 2 sides, between is internet. I finish with DHCP and now  I try to config NAT overload for 4 routers. When I send icmp packet through internet, it can't reach from this side to the other side. Sometimes it even can't reach the internet.

I click on packet and it show that the error is **The routing table does not have a route to the destination IP address. The router drops the packet** and I don't know how to fix it.

This is my NAT overload config :

```
en
conf t
access-list 1 permit 10.1.0.0 0.0.0.255
ip nat inside source list 1 interface Se1/0 overload
int f0/0
ip nat inside
int Se1/0
ip nat outside
```

and the same config for 3 other routers. Just fast forward time and you will see my dhcp IP address for all of my PCs

Link for my pkt file : https://mega.co.nz/#!BIdA2IIY!TFvcuee_Bmho9vs3uMX93AhIgox6eDj9icsyR25JRcY

- 10.1.0.0 for upper left building
- 10.2.0.0 for lower left building
- 10.3.0.0 for upper right building
- 10.4.0.0 for lower right building

If a pc has wrong ip just resend dhcp once or twice and it will have right IP

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an Dynamic NAT Pool, even with overload.

```
ip nat pool poolname beginningipaddress endingipaddress netmask mask
```

Comment: i tried ur solution but it still the same, it reaches to the router in internet but it drops packet